# Tor Browser for Mac 7.x crashes at startup

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, error, mac

Tor Browser 7.x for Mac always crashes at start. I tried the stable and experimental versions. No luck.

Any idea about what could be wrong?

Here is the crash report (at least the beginning):

```
Process:               firefox [4639]
Path:                  /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
Identifier:            org.torproject.torbrowser
Version:               7.0.1 (5217.2.2)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           firefox [4639]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-07-02 21:35:11.493 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1510)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        BD1A893C-C595-23C3-17AF-236FB080F0FD


Time Awake Since Boot: 11000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001096c1000-00000001096c4000 [   12K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   XUL                             0x000000010a8f8240 0x109e46000 + 11215424

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7675e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c19341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b767efa kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff82afe165 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff82afddcd _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7675e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c19341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7675e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c19341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7675e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c19341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7675e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c19341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:: Gecko_IOThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b767eca kevent + 10
1   XUL                             0x000000010a2901dc 0x109e46000 + 4497884

Thread 8:: Socket Thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b76707a __select + 10
1   libnss3.dylib                   0x0000000109da00a5 0x109c00000 + 1704101

Thread 9:: JS Watchdog
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767

Thread 10:: JS Helper
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   XUL                             0x000000010c95dbd1 0x109e46000 + 45186001
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b91a _pthread_start + 168
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c19351 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:: JS Helper
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   XUL                             0x000000010c95dbd1 0x109e46000 + 45186001
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b91a _pthread_start + 168
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c19351 thread_start + 13

Thread 12:: JS Helper
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   XUL                             0x000000010c95dbd1 0x109e46000 + 45186001
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b91a _pthread_start + 168
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c19351 thread_start + 13

Thread 13:: JS Helper
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   XUL                             0x000000010c95dbd1 0x109e46000 + 45186001
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b91a _pthread_start + 168
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c19351 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:: JS Helper
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   XUL                             0x000000010c95dbd1 0x109e46000 + 45186001
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b91a _pthread_start + 168
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c19351 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:: JS Helper
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   XUL                             0x000000010c95dbd1 0x109e46000 + 45186001

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b760f72 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7603b3 mach_msg + 55
2   XUL                             0x000000010cf1f21e 0x109e46000 + 51221022
3   ???                             0x0000000000010000 0 + 65536

Thread 17:: Hang Monitor
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libnss3.dylib                   0x0000000109db50fd PR_WaitCondVar + 253

Thread 18:: Timer
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libnss3.dylib                   0x0000000109db50e3 PR_WaitCondVar + 227

Thread 19:: Cache2 I/O
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libnss3.dylib                   0x0000000109db50fd PR_WaitCondVar + 253

Thread 20:: DataStorage
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libnss3.dylib                   0x0000000109db50fd PR_WaitCondVar + 253

Thread 21:: DataStorage
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libnss3.dylib                   0x0000000109db50fd PR_WaitCondVar + 253

Thread 22:: GMPThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libnss3.dylib                   0x0000000109db50fd PR_WaitCondVar + 253

Thread 23:: Compositor
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   XUL                             0x000000010a282f78 0x109e46000 + 4444024
3   ???                             0x8000000000000000 0 + 9223372036854775808

Thread 24:: ImgDecoder #1
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libnss3.dylib                   0x0000000109db50fd PR_WaitCondVar + 253

Thread 25:: ImgDecoder #2
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libnss3.dylib                   0x0000000109db50fd PR_WaitCondVar + 253

Thread 26:: ImageIO
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libnss3.dylib                   0x0000000109db50fd PR_WaitCondVar + 253

Thread 27:: RunProcess
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b767582 __wait4 + 10
1   XUL                             0x0000000109ef41ae 0x109e46000 + 713134

Thread 28:: IPDL Background
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libnss3.dylib                   0x0000000109db50fd PR_WaitCondVar + 253

Thread 29:: StreamTrans #3
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767

Thread 30:: DOM Worker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libnss3.dylib                   0x0000000109db50fd PR_WaitCondVar + 253

Thread 31:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b760f72 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7603b3 mach_msg + 55
2   XUL                             0x000000010cf1f0ae 0x109e46000 + 51220654
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b91a _pthread_start + 168
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c19351 thread_start + 13

Thread 32:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b766db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1c75e _pthread_cond_wait + 821
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff86a460d8 CVDisplayLink::waitUntil(unsigned long long) + 232
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff86a45ed1 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 511
4   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff86a459a9 startIOThread(void*) + 147
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b99d _pthread_body + 131
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c1b91a _pthread_start + 168
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff80c19351 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x8000000400000000  rbx: 0x00007fff56538700  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000008
  rdi: 0x00000001147d2160  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000008  rsp: 0x00007fff56538650
   r8: 0x000000000000006d   r9: 0x000000000000006d  r10: 0x00000000ffffff01  r11: 0x00007fff56538548
  r12: 0x00007fff565386f0  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00000001147d2160  r15: 0x0000000114fbf800
  rip: 0x000000010a8f8240  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x1096c1000 -        0x1096c3ff7 +org.torproject.torbrowser (7.0.1 - 5217.2.2) <7C5EEA52-97C0-3684-BD85-E13569C02825> /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
       0x1096cd000 -        0x1096e8ff7 +libmozglue.dylib (1) <7AE572D3-1E55-3A29-8C41-71AB872E6130> /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/libmozglue.dylib
       0x10994f000 -        0x10995afff +liblgpllibs.dylib (1) <850F8709-B4F5-3C96-9A09-7EA8972968F3> /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/liblgpllibs.dylib
       0x109c00000 -        0x109e0efff +libnss3.dylib (1) <C4DEB566-741C-3967-9321-A436C6091B39> /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/libnss3.dylib
       0x109e46000 -        0x10dd5cf77 +XUL (1) <6AD486A2-1DE9-388F-9CDF-D7BF246CA912> /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/XUL
       0x10e343000 -        0x10e37bff7 +libsoftokn3.dylib (1) <03224CD4-DCC3-3A2A-BBB2-FA8C74D6AEF5> /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/libsoftokn3.dylib
       0x112958000 -        0x1129d1fff +libfreebl3.dylib (1) <270608B4-904E-3E71-932B-2767F82D161D> /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/libfreebl3.dylib
       0x113342000 -        0x11339dfff +libnssckbi.dylib (???) <A216FC5F-F8A1-37A4-8865-6AE749FD1646> /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/libnssckbi.dylib
    0x7fff6f2f5000 -     0x7fff6f32ca47  dyld (360.22) <884763FC-CC0F-31CC-ACC4-75A805CE401D> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8074d000 -     0x7fff80a42fff  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1 - 807.2) <36413C45-36AF-34EF-9C0E-F18B31D1E565> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fff80a43000 -     0x7fff80a95fff  com.apple.ImageCaptureCore (7.0 - 7.0) <9F3123D8-29D2-332F-AD6B-AB9BF1A58022> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageCaptureCore.framework/Versions/A/ImageCaptureCore
    0x7fff80a9d000 -     0x7fff80aa8fff  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework (10.11 - 194) <6F827D0E-0F02-3B09-B2A8-252865EECA7F> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
    0x7fff80af7000 -     0x7fff80b38ff7  libGLU.dylib (12.1) <CD7A5916-3E3C-3EF3-A275-B281016B99CB> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
    0x7fff80b39000 -     0x7fff80b56ff7  com.apple.AppleVPAFramework (2.1.2 - 2.1.2) <707C6ED6-B8C0-38D4-B45A-7F2F689BD157> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleVPA.framework/Versions/A/AppleVPA
    0x7fff80bb9000 -     0x7fff80bcefff  com.apple.AppContainer (4.0 - 261.40.2) <F220E702-1C00-3BD2-9943-C7E75C3B4418> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppContainer.framework/Versions/A/AppContainer
    0x7fff80c18000 -     0x7fff80c21ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (138.10.4) <3DD1EF4C-1D1B-3ABF-8CC6-B3B1CEEE9559> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff80d4b000 -     0x7fff80dbafff  com.apple.datadetectorscore (7.0 - 460) <E8616F01-90AC-3863-B18C-426E6DD1ACDE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/DataDetectorsCore
    0x7fff80dbb000 -     0x7fff80dc7ff7  com.apple.OpenDirectory (10.11 - 194) <31A67AD5-5CC2-350A-96D7-821DF4BC4196> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff80dc8000 -     0x7fff80e68fff  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 972.34) <303B7C79-FB39-3A30-983B-78334FF39BB1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff81104000 -     0x7fff81d2dff7  com.apple.AppKit (6.9 - 1404.47) <F3411F6E-DD87-34D0-8C68-C69B2205E41D> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff81d86000 -     0x7fff81d92fff  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework (5.4.12 - 5.4.12) <71DA00B8-5EA2-326B-8814-59DB25512F65> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff81f93000 -     0x7fff82278ffb  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1136.2 - 1136.2) <2DBAFC9A-6CD6-351D-B1F4-87D81AA6D640> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff822ad000 -     0x7fff82321ff7  com.apple.Heimdal (4.0 - 2.0) <5D365381-8B5E-3259-8867-FC4A7D307BDE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Versions/A/Heimdal
    0x7fff8236d000 -     0x7fff823b9fff  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (11.2 - 472.2) <5AE8AA6B-CE09-397D-B0D4-0F9CCBF1F77D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff823ba000 -     0x7fff823e3fff  com.apple.ProtectedCloudStorage (1.0 - 1) <7436B2B3-943A-3500-B099-80F133B3E002> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtectedCloudStorage.framework/Versions/A/ProtectedCloudStorage
    0x7fff823e4000 -     0x7fff823f2fff  com.apple.IntlPreferences (2.0 - 192) <0108A3F2-6A11-30B1-965D-A167CC8131EC> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IntlPreferences.framework/Versions/A/IntlPreferences
    0x7fff823f3000 -     0x7fff823f5fff  com.apple.EFILogin (2.0 - 2) <38150198-DD7F-3C73-BCAA-C74BB376393A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EFILogin.framework/Versions/A/EFILogin
    0x7fff82407000 -     0x7fff825d0ff7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.3.0 - 1460) <5941D3B1-E38E-3593-8026-4FE56313259D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff825d1000 -     0x7fff825e4ff3  com.apple.SafariServices.framework (11603 - 11603.2.5) <FBF52A64-E7B7-3C11-B04E-13A0A4F4009E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SafariServices.framework/Versions/A/SafariServices
    0x7fff825f4000 -     0x7fff8261dffb  libRIP.A.dylib (970) <BA17C96B-83CC-3835-8AFD-CB5A69D3D26F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
    0x7fff8261e000 -     0x7fff82621fff  com.apple.IOSurface (108.2.4 - 108.2.4) <E7A63C0D-2FDA-3BC6-947D-07E3C4A13110> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff82622000 -     0x7fff82685fff  libAVFAudio.dylib (161.2) <1A98DBF3-490B-37FB-928A-AB1E36E6E5DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libAVFAudio.dylib
    0x7fff826be000 -     0x7fff826e8ff7  libc++abi.dylib (307.2) <922EFB36-0E9E-315B-8270-E81AC43472C0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff826e9000 -     0x7fff82ac1fef  com.apple.CoreAUC (214.0.0 - 214.0.0) <F80C19CA-6CD0-3052-9C22-0288A257CCC8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/Versions/A/CoreAUC
    0x7fff82ac2000 -     0x7fff82ac4ff7  com.apple.securityhi (9.0 - 55006) <AC151C58-A7AD-3ECF-B15D-5E09FF94FC23> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
    0x7fff82ac5000 -     0x7fff82af5ff3  com.apple.CoreAVCHD (5.8.0 - 5800.4.2) <4AAFB1C4-3708-30F9-ACFA-90564347204C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAVCHD.framework/Versions/A/CoreAVCHD
    0x7fff82af6000 -     0x7fff82b23fff  libdispatch.dylib (501.40.12) <C7499857-61A5-3D7D-A5EA-65DCC8C3DF92> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff82b2c000 -     0x7fff82b2dff7  libodfde.dylib (23) <F84CB160-D638-3190-B6F5-A262E9AF09F6> /usr/lib/libodfde.dylib
    0x7fff82d61000 -     0x7fff82db3fff  com.apple.CloudDocs (1.0 - 383.13) <5FD9138D-09D9-3B97-BBAD-5692E1687F30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocs.framework/Versions/A/CloudDocs
    0x7fff82db4000 -     0x7fff82e00ff7  com.apple.corelocation (1486.17 - 1615.38) <6336CFC5-9D7D-3B76-B263-56DD6EBD0B8D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/Versions/A/CoreLocation
    0x7fff82e1b000 -     0x7fff82e1ffff  libGIF.dylib (1461) <81C36C41-AEF2-33CC-BBCC-C43F48F63906> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff82f8c000 -     0x7fff82fdfff7  libc++.1.dylib (120.1) <8FC3D139-8055-3498-9AC5-6467CB7F4D14> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff82fe0000 -     0x7fff83069ff7  com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis (1.0 - 1) <E783E193-8FAD-3A1E-9139-2F56E564CDE7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PerformanceAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/PerformanceAnalysis
    0x7fff8316b000 -     0x7fff831a2ff7  com.apple.LDAPFramework (2.4.28 - 194.5) <9AE33BF2-FB17-342D-8F1E-5F83C6E6EB69> /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
    0x7fff831a3000 -     0x7fff831b1fff  com.apple.opengl (12.1.0 - 12.1.0) <12EBDE6A-2F44-3429-8337-2BB36870BFD8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff831b2000 -     0x7fff831b4fff  com.apple.CoreDuetDebugLogging (1.0 - 1) <7C932160-AC9C-3173-900F-98138E829CB3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework/Versions/A/CoreDuetDebugLogging
    0x7fff831b5000 -     0x7fff831c1fff  com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore (2.2.7 - 2.2.7) <6BA06290-D4A3-351C-87F9-B61EF61FF055> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeechRecognitionCore.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognitionCore
    0x7fff831c5000 -     0x7fff831c5fff  libenergytrace.dylib (10.40.1) <0A491CA7-3451-3FD5-999A-58AB4362682B> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
    0x7fff831d7000 -     0x7fff8324cfff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1179.50.2) <A509D3AE-9D48-31B7-89C7-326A7A2007B2> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff833a5000 -     0x7fff833c1ff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (67.40.1) <5748E8B2-F81C-34C6-8B13-456213127678> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff833c2000 -     0x7fff8356eff7  com.apple.avfoundation (2.0 - 1046.9.12) <41BDD03F-5545-3B9F-8DD7-7106485BAE8B> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation
    0x7fff83578000 -     0x7fff8397afff  libLAPACK.dylib (1162.2) <42238ED4-6B7A-39D0-BFF2-304A0C287213> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff83981000 -     0x7fff83989fff  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1223.10.1 - 1223.10.1) <7F5B7A23-BC1D-3FA9-A9B8-D534F1E1979A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fff8398a000 -     0x7fff8398ffff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.7 - 2.7) <9BB60809-3EA3-3881-8F2F-27EDBF9C8DE3> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff839fc000 -     0x7fff839fffff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (460.60.3) <2DDCB4AF-3037-34E5-A451-6846AFB9B85C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff83a00000 -     0x7fff83bceff3  com.apple.QuartzCore (1.11 - 410.14) <06A2BE20-38CB-3A89-9629-A782829DF977> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7fff83bcf000 -     0x7fff83c88ff7  libvMisc.dylib (563.5) <BF612F7D-FA3B-3F9F-8BE7-8D1BCB21ECC5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff83cbb000 -     0x7fff83cc0ff7  com.apple.AssetCacheServices (14.1 - 14.1) <5F249F84-660A-3E94-B073-6729E7ED56D9> 

.
.
.
.


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 493037
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=331.0M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=331.0M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=199.7M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=199.7M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                  2048K        2 
CG shared images                   144K        4 
CoreAnimation                       28K        4 
CoreUI image file                  192K        4 
Dispatch continuations            4096K        2 
IOKit                             31.0M        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        3 
MALLOC                            18.3M       11 
MALLOC guard page                   32K        7 
Memory Tag 242                      12K        2 
Process Corpse Info               2048K        2 
STACK GUARD                       56.1M       34 
Stack                             24.9M       34 
VM_ALLOCATE                        1.1G       78 
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)             388K        3         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__DATA                            30.3M      271 
__IMAGE                            528K        2 
__LINKEDIT                        92.7M       11 
__TEXT                           238.2M      274 
__UNICODE                          552K        2 
mapped file                      178.1M       16 
shared memory                     16.3M        8 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.8G      754 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.8G      754 

Model: MacBookPro5,2, BootROM MBP52.008E.B05, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.8 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.42f4
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT, NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334448302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.6f1 17910, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD TS256C, 251 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS21N
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB Receiver
USB Device: Scarlett 2i2 USB
USB Device: AXE-FX II
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It started out of the blue about 1 month ago and after reinstalling both firefox and tor, it still does not work.

Comment: Same for me.. I cannot open TOR anymore.. Crash at start.. Tried different version, update MacOS, tried in different computer.. Nothing!

Answer (score 1):

Create a account on https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/register and create a new ticket so that the TBB developers can fix the issue.